# Searching a text through search view

Tags: android, searchview

I wanted to search a word in a textview which contains a large amount of data. To accomplish it i added a search option in action bar and tried using setOnQueryTextListener. However i am not able to use method tv.getFilters().filter() on text view. This method works fine on array adapter.
Could you please suggest how to search text in text view

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

First call this method on onQueryTextChange(). See below.

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
           filterListByPattern(s, List);// List is TextView Large amount of data convert each word as a list item.
            return true;
        }
```

In filterListByPattern(),

```
 private void filterListByPattern(String s, ArrayList<String> mainList) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++)
    {
        String word = mainList.get(i);
        if(word.toLowerCase().toString().contains(s.toLowerCase().toString()))// if search word found in list
        {
            Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(word);        
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE));// change the color of the word in to blue.
            mainList.set(i, wordtoSpan.toString())//color changed word update to the List.
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++)
    {
        String word = mainList.get(i);
        tv.append(word);//append each word in List. search word will be blue color
    }


}
```